# Printf issues in Java

Tags: java, printf

Having a little bit of trouble in Java here with my printf statement. My code works properly, as I have tested it with println, I just need to get my spacing correct which is why I need to use printf. I've tried numerous ways of spacing and separating my strings and variables. I think part of the issue is that I have to use the "$" and that is messing with the printf statement. This is part of a school project so that is why I have to use printf instead of just doing a println statment. My code is as follows

```
for(double ten = 10.00; ten < 15.00; ten = ten + .75){
        /**
         * We use the variable tip to calculate a %20 tip and we use the
         * variable totalWithTip to calculate the total of the dinner price
         * and the tip added together.
         */
        double tip = ten * .2;
        double totalWithTip = ten + tip;

        System.out.printf("$%7s%4.2d$%13s%4.2d$%13s%4.2d\n", ten, tip, totalWithTip);
    }
```

I need the output to look like

```
  Dinner Price          20% tip         Total
---------------------------------------------------
      $10.00            $ 2.00            $12.00
      $10.75            $ 2.15            $12.90
      $11.50            $ 2.30            $13.80
      $12.25            $ 2.45            $14.70
      $13.00            $ 2.60            $15.60
      $13.75            $ 2.75            $16.50
      $14.50            $ 2.90            $17.40
```

Comment: https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs160/.Summer16/resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, this might be a solution:

```
System.out.printf("%7s$%4.2f%13s$ %4.2f%13s$%4.2f\n"," ",  ten, " ", tip, " ", totalWithTip);
```

In your example, the spaces were put after data. Also, you just need %f for a double (or float), with the .2 specifying the decimal places.

Comment: Thank you! this is super close!!! I think I need to add one more " " before ten with some spacing, I will try in a moment and let you know!

Comment: Code dumps with no explanation are poor answers.  A good answer explains the mistake, and how and why you have corrected it.

Comment: Great catch! I have aggregated them into a single line.

Comment: Question though, how do I add the space for the middle column? The $ 2.00 has a space between the number and the dollar sign.

Comment: If the space is permanent, you can include it in the template where applicable. See the updated example.

Comment: By the way, while your template example is not wrong, I would recommend using the template used in @jogo's answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.printf("$%.2f $%.2f $%.2f \n", ten, tip, totalWithTip);
```

You just need %f for a double (or float), with the .2 specifying the decimal places.

For the spaces, you use the 'c' character, prefixed with the number of spaces. E.g. %6c will print 6 characters.

```
System.out.printf("$%.2f%6c$%.2f%6c$%.2f\n", ten, ' ', tip,' ',totalWithTip);
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves my decimal issue, but that does not solve my spacing issue! Should I add a %6d before the first one to get the six blank spaces?

Comment: Check the amended answer

Comment: Question though, how do I add the space for the middle column? The $ 2.00 has a space between the number and the dollar sign.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```
System.out.printf("%7s$%-13.2f$%-13.2f$%-13.2f\n", " ", ten, tip, totalWithTip);
```

The '-' aligns the output of the parameter to the left and adds padding characters to the right.